# android facebook share problem on device

Tags: android, authentication, facebook

I have used sample from [AndroidFacebookSample](https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidFacebookSample) it works fine on emulator but on device it is diverted to inbuilt facebook intent.
Authentication dialog doesn't appear on device but normal facebook app authentication screen appears.
thanks in advance.

Comment: hey, try to explore the files provided as facebooksdk and understand the sequence. you will surely get result in 20 minutes. Tell us, if you didn't get it...

Comment: @Farhan I have been exploring this from yesterday...The problem is on device implementation only...

Comment: ok, look into authorize function in facebook.java file. try to comment out the singlesignon and use startdialog()... something like this..

Comment: @Farhan I have found it in Facebook.java !!! here First preference is given to SingleSignOn..commented it.. I'll Let you know after implementation on real device.   Thanks for great help.

Comment: Good to know. let me post that as a answer so that it could be easy to find by other peoples....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look into authorize function in facebook.java file. try to comment out the singlesignon and use startdialog() only... something like this.. hope it helps.