# android facebook app interupt facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook

I've experimenting with facebook android sdk these times...

btw I'm using the facebook to android integration tutorial, that pops dialog layout...
link http://integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/

this the code that i use:

```
public class Sharefb extends Activity {
private static final String APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream"};

private static final String TOKEN = "access_token";
    private static final String EXPIRES = "expires_in";
    private static final String KEY = "facebook-credentials";

private Facebook facebook;
private String messageToPost;

public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
        Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
        editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
        return editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
        facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
        return facebook.isSessionValid();
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    restoreCredentials(facebook);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("facebookMessage");
    if (facebookMessage == null){
        facebookMessage = "Test wall post";
    }
    messageToPost = facebookMessage;
}

public void doNotShare(View button){
    finish();
}
public void share(View button){
    if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        loginAndPostToWall();
    }
    else {
        postToWall(messageToPost);
    }
}

public void loginAndPostToWall(){
     facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
}

public void postToWall(String message){
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", message);
        facebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, new WallPostDialogListener());
}

class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        saveCredentials(facebook);
        if (messageToPost != null){
        postToWall(messageToPost);
    }
    }
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        //finish();
    }
    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        //finish();
    }
    public void onCancel() {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
        //finish();
    }
}

class WallPostDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                if (postId != null) {
                showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
            } else {
                showToast("Wall post cancelled!");
            }
            finish();
        }
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
    public void onCancel() {
        showToast("Wall post cancelled!");
        finish();
    }
    }

private void showToast(String message){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Unfortunately, every single time i make a request... the window just blink in a few seconds and then finish...

later, when i delete the facebook app on my emulator, it works fine and I can post new message on my wall...

is there anything wrong with this?
I hope U guys will find out soon

Tank you!

Comment: some of you maybe have problem with window overlay or some sort of it..., BUT it's not a problem! i've made the layout independent by removing theme.dialog on my manifest and still I can't post my message until i remove facebook app on my emulator...

Comment: i am not sure but check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786442/android-facebook-share-problem-on-device

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for your problem; see here:

```
public void loginAndPostToWall() {
    facebook.authorize(PostwallActivity.this, PERMISSIONS,
        new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

previously tour using this for login replace this line to:

```
public void loginAndPostToWall() {
    facebook.authorize(PostwallActivity.this, 
        PERMISSIONS,Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

you got a output and get your app login page only but not a main facebook app login page.