# facebook authentication dialog disappearing instantly

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am using the latest facebook android SDK but when I call the `mFaceboo.authorize(...)`  method the dialog box is not appearing instead a full screen page is showing up for a second and instantly disappears.

I noticed that i have recently updated the official facebook client app in my device. When I have removed the updates from the facebook client the Authentication dialog is working fine.

But the problem is that I can't force users of my app not to update their facebook client app. Is anyone facing same problem or knows the solution please help.

Following is the snippet that I am using.

```
   mFacebook.authorize(MyProfileScreen.this, PERMISSIONS, new DialogListener() {


        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

            /*
             * Here we'll the token so we can store it for the further use.
             */
            Log.v(TAG, "Facebook Login Success! ");

            launchProfileScreen();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v(TAG, "onFacebookError"+e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v(TAG, "onError"+e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v(TAG, "onCancel");
        }
    });
```

Also calling

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Does your logcat show any error by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this SO question: [android facebook share problem on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786442/android-facebook-share-problem-on-device/5794980#5794980) that may help.

Comment: thanks guys I didn't got the time to check I hope it will work.